# How to tell which modules are installed in phpBB3

Tags: phpbb3

I am used to Drupal, and it is fairly clear with Drupal  which modules are on a server. I am new to phpBB and looking to learn just enough to migrate an install to Drupal. I can see that phpBB has 'modules' but I can't see how to tell which modules are are Installed or enabled.

From what I can see, installing modules in phpbb3 is a lot of hacking flies in the install, is this true? Is there a way to tell what is installed. even if I have to run some grep over the code?

Answer (score 1):

Installing modules is 'complicated' in PHPBB3. However, anything in the [MOD Database](http://www.phpbb.com/customise/db/modifications-1/) can be installed (or uninstalled) using [AutoMOD](http://www.phpbb.com/mods/automod/). This should make your life easier if you are looking for mods in the MOD Database. The 'complicated' part of the install is any Do-It-Yourself instructions. You have to execute these by hand. This is the 'hacking files' that you mentioned. It seems to be fairly common in the 3.0.x versions of PHPBB. 3.1 is supposed to reduce this, but PHPBB development is slow. 3.1 entered [feature freeze](http://blog.phpbb.com/2010/07/20/phpbb-ascraeus-3-1-feature-freeze/) in July of 2010

A basic tutorial to install a mod using AutoMOD is [available](http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=225&t=1367815).

AutoMOD also allows you to see which modules have been installed (using AutoMOD). If you manually installed something by hacking through the install script yourself, it won't appear on this list.

Comment: unfortunately if MODs aren't installed using AutoMOD and are edited by hand (this is how I install all of mine as I don't trust the automated tool) then there is no accurate way to see what has been added. There may be extra options available in the ACP, the majority (by no means all) can be found under the .MOD tab